# Citation style with first letters of author's lastname

Tags: biblatex

I'm searching for a citation style. I'm using `biblatex` and I want the following citation using the first letters of the last name and the year of publishing:

- For only one author the reference should consider the first three letters and the year like: [Lot08] for the name Loth and the year 2008.
- For more than one author the reference should look like this [BMCW12] which contains the first letters of the lastname of the authors (Becker, Meier, Conrady, Wolf) and the year.

I know this is very similar to the alphabetic style but I don't want to get the plus inside the cite like [BMC+12]. In addition I want to fix the number of letters to 4 even if there are more authors.

Is there such a citation style available or do I have to adjust the alphabetic style?

Comment: Have you looked at the package `biblatex-trad` that emulates the abbrev style?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can customise the alphabetic label style quite heavily with `\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate` (see §4.5.4 *Labels*, pp. 163-169 of the [`biblatex` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)). In your case that is not necessary, however.

You only need the add the two options

```
maxalphanames=4, minalphanames=4
```

to your `biblatex` call to get the number of names as desired.

And then

```
\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{}
```

gets rid of the "+" that shows that authors have been omitted.

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,maxalphanames=4,minalphanames=4]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,aksin,companion}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```